# Having trouble with load data local infile writing to database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am new to php and mysqli, and am attempting to put together a stats site for a game that I play.  In a nut shell this code 1) looks up by user (via URL) the last X sorties (1 here but can change to any number), 2) Curl's that result, 3) places it into /tmp/sorties.csv, then 4) loads data local infle /tmp/sortie.csv to my database.

It does connect to the database (member table) and look up by member/player name (echos back in "updating for"), as well as the game information (shows 1 sortie per player who has data in the game database) --I've commented out the header so as to see what is echod back.

my site is hosted buy a 3rd party, but is using sql 5.5.32, php 5.3.13, and is a Linux/Debian platform.  Any (and all) assistance is greatly appreciated, I actually wrote the vast majority of this by using some of the questions and answers provided here.  I do have an only MySQL version of this code that is having the same error (started not working 2 days ago) and am hoping that updating to mysqli will correct the issue.  The database fields do match both in number and data-type.

```
include 'Data/openi.php';

//Collect player name info
$query = "SELECT name FROM Members";
$result=$link->query($query); 

// Array
$rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
        {
          $rows[] =$row['name'];
        }

// collect sortie data
foreach ($rows as $player) 
{ 
$url = "http://myurlforlookup.php?username=".$player."&startsortie=0&sortiecount=1";
$path = '/tmp/sortie.csv' ;
// echo Player name -- works
echo "<br /><br />Updating for ".$player."<br />" ; 

//Curl to tmp file (aka $path)    
$ch = curl_init($url);
 if($ch === false)
     {
     die('Failed to create curl handle');
     }
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 if(!curl_exec($ch))
    {
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }
 curl_close($ch);
 file_put_contents($path,$result );

//show sortie (post Curl) data on screen -- Works 
 echo $result  ;

// Input to the database -- Not working
 
 $sqli = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/sortie.csv'
                 INTO TABLE Sorties
                 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\''
                 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                 " ;

$done=$link->query($sqli);
if (!$done) echo mysqli_error($sqli);
/*if (mysql_affected_rows() >= 1) {
 $message = "The user was successfully updated!";
 }
 else
 {
 $message = "</br>The user update failed:</br> ";
 $message .= mysql_error();
 }

 echo $message;
*/

} 
$result->close();
$link->close();
return $rows;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And can you believe it - while digging around this site for a completely different issue, I fond this question ["Load data local infile" command not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739757/load-data-local-infile-command-not-allowed?rq=1)

When I adjusted my sqli connect string to the suggestions here, my code magically works.... kind of fun... love finding solutions.  Though if anyone has input for optimization I'm also open to those suggestions